# Help Reset setTimeOut for make a Traffic Light in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i want to make traffic light that will work automatic ,
like i did but after 19 its will reset and start again the function
so its will see like traffic light that never stop and will repeat
him self

- 1. 10 sec for the red light
- 2. 2 sec yellow light
- 3. 6 sec green light
- 4. 1 sec yellow light
- 5. and repat........

ty for all the help !!

```js
 function changecolor(){
var red = document.querySelector('#Red') 
var yellow = document.querySelector('#Yellow') 
var green = document.querySelector('#Green') 
 
setTimeout(function(){ red.style.background= "red" },5); // on red

setTimeout(function(){ yellow.style.background= "yellow"  //on yellow + off red
red.style.background= "#FF4A4D" 
},10000); 

setTimeout(function(){ yellow.style.background= "#F1FF73"  //on green + off yellow
green.style.background= "green"
},12000); 

setTimeout(function(){ yellow.style.background= "yellow" //on yellow + off green
green.style.background= "#43B560"
 },18000); 
setTimeout(function(){ red.style.background= "red" //off yellow + on red 
yellow.style.background= "#F1FF73"
 },19000); 

 setTimeout(changecolor(), 19005);

 
}
```

```css
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}


h1{
margin-left:45%;
}

button{
margin-left:49%;
margin-top:2%;
color:white;
border: 1px solid blue;
background:black;
}

#Red{
display:block;
background:#FF4A4D;
width:15%;
height:20vh;
border-radius:50%;
margin-left:45%;
margin-top:1%;
}

#Yellow{
display:block;
background:#F1FF73;
width:15%;
height:20vh;
border-radius:50%;
margin-left:45%;
margin-top:1%;
}

#Green{
display:block;
background:#43B560;
width:15%;
height:20vh;
border-radius:50%;
margin-left:45%;
margin-top:1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <title>Traffic Light</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Traffic Light</h1>
 <div id="Red"></div>
 <div id="Yellow"></div>
 <div id="Green"></div>
 <button onclick="changecolor()">Click To Start</button>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: its dont work ... i need to reset the traffic light after 19sec that they will start again .. how i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/t8vkmLew/4/).

```
function changecolor(){
var red = document.querySelector('#Red')    
var yellow = document.querySelector('#Yellow')  
var green = document.querySelector('#Green')    
if(time == 20) {
     red.style.background= "red";
     yellow.style.background = "#F1FF73";
     time = 1;
}

if(time % 10 == 0) {
     yellow.style.background= "yellow"
     red.style.background= "#FF4A4D" 

}
 if(time % 12 == 0) {
     green.style.background= "green";
     yellow.style.background = "#F1FF73";
}   
 if(time % 18 == 0) {
     yellow.style.background= "yellow" //on yellow + off green
     green.style.background= "#43B560"
}   

 if(time % 19 == 0) {
      red.style.background= "red" //off yellow + on red 
      yellow.style.background= "#F1FF73"
}   

 time+=1;

}
```