# Traffic light Sequence Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code for a traffic light's sequences. I was wondering how I could add a timer in to change the traffic light colour every 3 seconds, for example, when the button is clicked. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  
  <h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1> 
  <p>This is  my Traffic Light script</p> 
  <img id="light" src="./assets/red.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>  
  <script> 
    var list = ["./assets/red.jpg","./assets/redamber.jpg", "./assets/green.jpg","./assets/amber.jpg" ];
    var index = 0;
    function changeLights() {
      index = index + 1;      
      if (index == list.length) 
        index = 0;      
      var image = document.getElementById('light');     
      image.src = list[index]; 
    } 
  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(changeLights,3000)`...

Comment: Has your teacher taught you about [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920320/traffic-light-sequence-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653900/what-is-wrong-with-this-traffic-light-javascript-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906626/overlooking-needed-with-html-and-javascript-traffic-light-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920989/how-to-create-an-automatic-traffic-light-sequence-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747318/help-reset-settimeout-for-make-a-traffic-light-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796563/how-to-create-button-for-traffic-light-code-in-javascript

Comment: Can we auto tag "traffic light sequence" questions as duplicates?

Comment: Sure, feel free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setInterval` function.

The first parameter is the function you want to call and the second parameter is how often it should be called, in milliseconds.

```
var timer = setInterval(changeLights,3000);
```

```js
var list = ["./assets/red.jpg","./assets/redamber.jpg",     "./assets/green.jpg","./assets/amber.jpg" ];
var index = 0;
function changeLights() {
     index = index + 1;      
if (index == list.length) 
index = 0;      
var image = document.getElementById('light');     
image.src=list[index]; } 
  var timer = setInterval(changeLights,3000);
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1> 
<p>This is  my Traffic Light script</p> 
<img id="light" src="./assets/red.jpg"> <button type="button" 
onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!!

Comment: If you wouldn't mind you could accept the answer by clicked the green checkmark under the voting button for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static timer with setTimeout(function, time);

In your case, if you want a repeating timer every 3 seconds constantly, you can have setTimeout run every time the changeLights() function ends

See [w3schools article on timing](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
var timer;
function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;      
    if (index == list.length) 
    index = 0;      
    var image = document.getElementById('light');     
    image.src=list[index];

    timer = setTimeout("changeLights", 3000);
}
```

With that change, once you start the lights, the function will repeat every 3 seconds.

The timer variable also alows you to stop the timer (perhaps in your case with another button) with:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this really helped!!