# How to create button for traffic light code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I intend to include a button in my traffic light code so that the user can click on it to activate the traffic light however, i am unsure of where to place it in my code.

This is my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "traffic light_1.png"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "traffic light_2.png"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "traffic light_3.png"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "traffic light_2.png"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="traffic light_1.png" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<4)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",3000);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the button wherever you like inside the body tag.

```
<input type="button" name="start" value="Start/stop Traffic light" onclick="startStop()">
```

Remove the `setTimeout` and the `slideit()` initial call.

```
var step=1;
function slideit()
{
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
    if(step<4)
        step++;
    else
        step=1;
}
```

And add the `startStop` function below and the `working` variable declaration.

```
var working;
function startStop() {
    if (typeof working != 'undefined') working = clearInterval(working);
    else working=setInterval("slideit()", 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but when i click on the button, it does not activate the traffic light. Is there something i havent done?

Comment: Do you get any error in the javascript console of your browser? You can find a working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/rjch1qp8/1/