# Javascript button issues for image slideshow

Tags: javascript

I want to fix the button so that the user can click on it in order to start the traffic light slideshow. At the moment, it is interfering with the loop which means that when the user clicks on the button it will fasten the slideshow rather than start it.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "traffic light_1.png"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "traffic light_2.png"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "traffic light_3.png"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "traffic light_2.png"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="traffic light_1.png" width="800" height="500" name="slide" /></p>

<button onclick="slideit()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<4)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",4000);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: fyi `eval` is a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812288/why-is-eval-unsafe-in-javascript

Comment: search SO for "why is eval a bad idea"

Comment: What do you think i should do?

Comment: Don't autostart: remove the last call to `slideIt();` - Also, better use `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem

Comment: @AlonEitan Why a jsfiddle and not a stack snippet?

Comment: @le_m Stack snippet is also fine (Although it's not as good as jsfiddle when it come to debugging IMHO)

Comment: @le_m i tried this method but still doesnt work but just adds two buttons that serve no purpose. Are you sure that is everything to it?

Comment: Please, close the previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796563/how-to-create-button-for-traffic-light-code-in-javascript/37797073#37797073

Comment: @Jack Why don't you follow the answer given in your identical previous question??

Comment: It does not work for me so i am feel like i need to find another way of approaching this

Answer (score 0):

With

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = ...
```

you are creating `<img src="..." >` [Image()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

Suppose you want to **replace** the`src`. Therefore one can set an array with the URLs :

```
var urls = ["img2.jpg", ..., "img1.jpg"];
```

Give the setted `<img>` an **id** and access it with `document.getElementById("slide");`

Then you have something like this :

```js
var urls = ["http://unsplash.it/300/150?image=2", "http://unsplash.it/300/150?image=3", "http://unsplash.it/300/150?image=4",
"http://unsplash.it/300/150?image=1"];

var step = 0;

function slideit() {
    var s = document.getElementById("slide");
    s.src = urls[step];
    if(step < 3) {
     step++;
    } else {
     step = 0;
    }
}

slideit();
```

```html
<p>
    <img id="slide" src="http://unsplash.it/300/150?image=1" width="300" height="200" name="slide" />
</p>

<button onclick="slideit()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: var urls = ["traffic light_1.png", "traffic light_2.png", "traffic light_3.png", "traffic light_4.png"];
var step = 0;

function slideit() {
    var s = document.getElementById("slide");
    s.src = urls[step];
    if(step < 4) {
     step++;
    } else {
     step = 0;
    }
}
<p>
    <img id="slide" src="traffic light_1.PNG" width="500" height="300" name="slide" />
</p>

<button onclick="slideit()">Click me</button>

Comment: The urls are from my files and not from the web. Does this make a difference?

Comment: I've updated my answer. `var urls = [second img, third img, ..., first img]` and in the HTML `<img src="first img">`. I hope this is clear.

Comment: What should happen, if you click the button ? Should it slide to the next image **or** should it only **start** a automatically slideshow ?